# I want to call some code when my web browser application opens

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been looking for some time now to find (I know it sounds stupid) how I can call some code when I start my application. I'm using C# on Windows Forms. I know this all sounds stupid but I usually just use Unity3D which has a simple method:

```
void Start() 
{
    //Whatever goes here
}
```

I'm trying to make a web browser.

Comment: Why are you building a web browser?

Comment: are you talking about form's `Load` event?

Comment: If only there was a place to find documentation on Winforms, or perhaps a search engine which you could use to find the [entry point to a Winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992837/where-is-the-main-method-in-a-forms-application).

Answer (score 0):

you can put code in the winforms generated main

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // you code goes here
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

or in the load event of the MainForm

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: So I've put `if (tabControl.TabCount == 1)
            {
                btnRemoveTab.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnRemoveTab.Enabled = true;
            }`  in but it references to things in Form1. How would I carry them over to this.

Comment: put them in the form load event

Answer (score -1):

You can go to global file and put the code inside Application start event.

If you want to run the code when a certain webpage opens, u can put it in the load event created in the .cs file of the page.